# Axios VS Postman request get different responses

Tags: javascript, axios, postman

Hello guys I came across a strange issue I got with connection to an API.

While I am using Postman everything goes well but if I make the request with Axios the response is different. So to give you an example I want to get a client with id 616;

Client

```
await axios
        .post("/api/getClient", {
          id: 616,
        }).then(data => console.log(data))
```

Backend

```
// GET CLIENT
app.post('/api/getClient', async (req, res) => {
  const d = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/client/account/:client_id`, {
    headers: headers,
    data: {
      id: req.body.id
    }
  })
  res.send(d.data)
  res.end()
});
```

Response from axios look like this

```
data: {
  error: false,
  user: {
    profile: null,
    user_addresses: [],
    safe_credits: 0,
    rating: 5
  }
}
```

From Postman

```
{
    "error": false,
    "user": {
        "profile": {
            "id": 616,
            "phone_number": "07744444444",
            "country_code": "44",
            "email": "email@example.com",
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "password": null,
            "os": "iOS",
            "token": "0c9c09e7dc2f009b4cfdb2e4666ead9e",
            "version": "",
            "photo": "",
            "gender": "male",
            "registered_date": "2020-05-08T14:55:05.000Z",
            "enabled": 1,
            "socketId": "",
            "stripe_id": "cus_HF1eUUdada54JKN"
        },
        "user_addresses": [],
        "safe_credits": 0,
        "rating": 5
    }
}
```

Comment: We will have to look at your postman collection to help you

Comment: export the postman request as curl please

Comment: Check for the headers you are passing to the postman request. You might be missing something in the axios request

Comment: @DeepakTerse I have it in JSON

Comment: @MarkusHayner share it with us

Comment: @PaulCosma curl --location --request GET 'http://platform.eyesafe.london:3000/client/account/616' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic MjM5ODRFYzdCNzU1QTU0MTVjYTA4NENGOTQzMjAzQzY4NzkzZkEyNzpGOGZDMDdCMDM1NjBmYUQzN0I3RmVBMDI1YTM0RjIzZDFDY0I3MDQ5' \
--data-raw '{
 "id":69000
}'

Comment: @DeepakTerse is quite heavy

Comment: @MarkusHayner wha is ```{ "id":69000 }``` in your curl request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213970/discussion-between-markus-hayner-and-deepak-terse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `data` in your request, you should just be able to append the ID to your API URL:

```
 const d = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/client/account/${req.body.id}`, {
   ...
 });
```

Comment: The API uses the path to define the type of request (client, account) and the parameters (account ID). We're just sticking the account ID onto the URL where the API expects it.

Comment: Ok and how am i suppose to work with a path which is not using variables in path for example localhost:3000/ will receive phone, email, firstName, lastName, password to register a new user. how shall I work with this if not in data?

Comment: Most likely you will be making a POST request (as opposed to GET) using Axios. In that case the information that you are posting is expected to be in the data.

Answer (score -1):

I had recently a similar issue.

In postman make sure you delete any cookies, as this might affect results.

Postman stores cookies between different requests on the same domain. While axios (or any other backend library) might not.

Under the "Send" button in postman, check the cookies, delete any cookies you find there and re-execute. This might give you the same result you're having in axios.